# How do I setup my local Git repository to work with a remote server?

Tags: git, version-control, netbeans

I'm trying to get up and running with git. I have set up a repository on my remote server, where my live site sits.
I want to do some work locally on a copy of that site, then push the changes back to the remote server.

How can I checkout/clone a copy of the site from the remote repository?

Can I do this via the Netbeans Git plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you repo is already set up, you should have git URL to it, it typically looks like

```
git://server/somerepo.git
```

to clone repository

```
git clone git://server/somerepo.git
```

you will get folder somerepo, it will be cloned repository that you own. As soon as you ready to push changes:

```
git add -A
git commit -m 'my changes'
git push origin master
```

Comment: thanks. I take it that origin is the alias for my remote server repo? So git push origin master would push the changes on the local repo to the remote repo?

Comment: yes, as you did the clone origin would be initialized with remote repository (one you cloned from)